# Lazy load properties from Entitry Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I am looking for a way in which I can only load properties when they are read.

Lets take my use case for example:

I have several dashboards, The way it currently works is that the controller builds the `DashbaordViewModel` and then passes it through to the `View` which then makes use of some or all of the properties.

```
  public ActionResult Home()
    {
        return View(new DashboardModel(_db));
    }
```

My dashboard view model looks like so:

```
public class DashboardModel
{
    private readonly DbEntities _db;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>     
    public DashboardModel(DbEntities db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    [DisplayName("Number Of Subjects")]
    public int NumberOfSubjects => _db.Subjects.Count();

    [DisplayName("Number Of Enabled Subjects")]
    public int NumberOfEnabledSubjects => _db.Subjects.Count(x => x.Enabled);
 }
```

I then make use of the view model to display these stats in my Razor view.

However as the `DashboardModel` grows bigger and bigger and the queries get more and more complex I have started being aware of how ineffective this is. Especially because I generally don't use All of the properties in every view. Sometimes I pass the `DashboardModel` through to a view, just to make use of 1 or 2 properties.

So what I want to know is, how can I make the PC only execute the LINQ query on the DB when I actually try and access that property in my view.

If there could be an `async` version that would be even better.

Comment: Do you have to store the count properties inside the model? Why not store them in the view models and update them as necessary, depending on the requirement.

Comment: I may be way off here, but I think EF has that built in... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Per the other two comments, lazy loading is built in. It's the Count()'s that are triggering query execution. There's no way around that unless you specifically do the counts in another API call and bring them in asynchronously.

Comment: Thing is that they are all going to be called when the viewmodel is serialized to be sent to the view.

Comment: You could turn these properties or subsets of properties into a set of microservices, expose them via Web API controller(s), and call them from a javascript framework (like angular or even jquery if it stays simple) as needed. Then you only load the html and javascript library(s) from your View (no data or at least no data as it relates to this).

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you should set your properties as virtual to take advantage of the lazy loading.